# How do I store phone numbers in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, data-integrity, data-validation

Let's assume I want to store phone numbers in a database. I may accept phone numbers from outside of the United States. How would I go about storing these phone numbers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164 is the standard

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## [`libphonenumber`](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

When possible always use the canonical form. The more normalized the form the better. If there is a standard, use it. For this problem, let's use Google's [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/tree/master/cpp), by proxy of [pg-libphonenumber](https://github.com/blm768/pg-libphonenumber).

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_libphonenumber;
```

This currently installs the `phone_number` type which has comparison operators and functions. It stores the number in an international canonical form. This is the best compromise in my opinion.

```
parse_phone_number('textnumber', 'CountryCode');
```

Because we can tell when phone numbers equal each other and we provide an internal normal form, we can do this..

```
SELECT parse_phone_number('03 7010 1234', 'AU') = parse_phone_number('(03) 7010 1234', 'AU');
```

(returns true). This also means that `DISTINCT` works so we can do this to get the effect you seem to want above.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT DISTINCT parse_phone_number(ph, 'AU')
  FROM ( VALUES
    ('0370101234'),
    ('03 7010 1234'),
    ('(03) 7010 1234')
  ) AS t(ph);
SELECT 1
```

That puts in..

```
 parse_phone_number 
--------------------
 +61 3 7010 1234
(1 row)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the package seems to be in *alpha* state for more than 1 year... High care recommended if you try to use it in production.

Comment: @joanolo You are right, but is seems that a new contributor, Evan Carroll, has made a new commit just today... Somebody would consider all this self-promotion on Evan’s part but I upvoted this self-answer also because he is actively contributing to the extension...

Comment: I only "contributed" to the documentation. And, I did so before I posted this in the same fashion I always do to improve documentation. I'm not a "contributor", in any useful sense. I don't have a commit bit. I don't write C++ code. I'm just passionate about having libphonenumber binding in PgSQL and others knowing about them and how to use them.

Comment: Contributing to the documentation is contributing. ;) And I’ll use libphonenumber in a (safe, non critical) project of mine because of this post. Thank you.

Comment: For what its worth, we use libphonenumber to normalize the number before it goes into the database - that way we don't need to be dependent on (at the time of writing) alpha-quality postgres plugins which can't be used in RDS and other cloud-based postgres deployments.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution without extension `pg_libphonenumber`.

- Domain [`phone.sql`](https://github.com/rin-nas/postgresql-patterns-library/blob/master/domains/phone.sql) for validation phone number in international `E.164` format.
- Function [`phone_parse.sql`](https://github.com/rin-nas/postgresql-patterns-library/blob/master/functions/phone_parse.sql) to parse phone number into 3 parts: `country_code`, `area_code`, `local_number`.